# Process messages from Amazon SQS Dead Letter Queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I want to process messages from an Amazon SQS Dead Letter Queue.

What is the best way to process them?

1. Receive messages from dead letter queue and process it.
2. Receive messages from dead letter queue put back in main queue and then process it?

I just need to process messages from dead letter queue once in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the message ended up in the Dead Letter Queue for a reason, after failing several times.

It would *not* be a good idea to put it back in the main queue because, presumably, **it would fail again** and you would create an infinite loop.

Initially, dead messages should be examined manually to determine the causes of failure. Then, based on this information, an **alternate flow** could be developed.

Comment: There might be some situations like network down or some other issues from the client then all the messages will be stacked in dead letter queue. then processing those messages was required. In this case I am thinking to find out the better way. If I put back in the regular queue then will the regular queue gets over loaded ?

Comment: What if there was a bug in the triggered lambda function of the main queue, now the bug is fixed the lambda function can re-process them.

Comment: You're assuming we haven't already fixed the issue after manually inspecting the messages themselves. Once we've implemented a fix and we're ready to re-do the broken messages we still need that `alternate flow` you're talking about.

Comment: @anon58192932 Yes, that's fair enough. In that case, you would need some code to retrieve messages from the DLQ and send a new message (with the same content) to the original queue.

Comment: It looks like you can copy the JSON message contents from the DLQ and paste them as a new message in the original queue and finally delete the DLQ message. Not the prettiest strategy and won't work for large DLQ sizes but can work.

Comment: so there is no way to do it for all of them? only one by one??? @anon58192932

Comment: As John said @dang you'd have to write code to programmatically read the queue and resubmit the messages. I'm not sure how to do it on the web interface itself in bulk.

Comment: @anon58192932 yep, i think there should be a button which does it for you after u fix some bugs..

Answer (score 2):

After careful consideration of various options, I am going with the option 2 "**Receive messages from dead letter queue put back in main queue and then process it**" you mentioned.

Make sure that while transferring the messages from one queue messages are not lost.

Before putting messages from DLQ to main queue, make sure that the errors faced in the main listener (mainly coding errors if any) are resolved or if any network issues are resolved.

The listener of the main queue has retried the message already and retrying it again. So please make sure to either skip already successful steps of message processing in case message is being retried. Also revert successfully processed steps in case of any errors. (This will will help in the message retry as well.)

DLQ is meant for unexpected errors. So you may have an **on-demand job** for doing this.